# iOS Segue Issue, all method in the destination controller is called but doesn't show the view

Tags: ios5, segue

I use segue to perform the page jump from table cell in my.

I randomly got this issue in different places in my app. currently two places, the index table view and the setting table view (the setting one occurs first time this morning).

Methods in the destination controller are called according to the log."viewDidLoad","setup fetch result controller"..etc, but the app just stops there, doesn't response to any of my actions any more.

Any idea about that? Thanks in advance.